# How to view the contents of another persons enderchest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using 1.12. `/data get entity @p EnderItems` doesn't work as it isn't seen as a command.

Comment: you could use the spigot Essentials plugin, it has a /invsee command and you can also use it for Ender chests

Comment: The /data command was changed in the aquatic update (1.13) with the syntax you're trying to use. That command won't work unless you update. There is probably another solution pre-flattening, which is why this is a comment.